# How to stop authorization WebFilter from redirecting me to homepage every time I invoke a request from another page

Tags: jsf, servlet-filters

I am trying to build a simple Login/Signup Interface using *JSF*, *Hibernate* and *WildFly*. I have used the following AuthorizationFilter class so far in order to redirect to the login page if the session is not authenticated.
I also implemented a simple User CRUD view called

> /admin.xhtml

which manages user entries in the DB. Now my problem is that every time I click a button to CRUD a User entry in admin.xhtml I am automatically redirected to the login page. When I disable this WebFilter everything works perfectly fine with the CRUD Interface. 
How can I prevent this WebFilter from redirecting me after I have logged in and created a session?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebFilter(filterName = "AuthFilter", urlPatterns = { "*.xhtml" })
 public class AuthorizationFilter implements Filter {

public AuthorizationFilter() {
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {

        HttpServletRequest reqt = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpSession ses = reqt.getSession(false);

        String reqURI = reqt.getRequestURI();
        if (reqURI.contains("/login.xhtml")
                || (ses != null && ses.getAttribute("username") != null)
                || reqURI.contains("/public/")
                || reqURI.contains("javax.faces.resource"))
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        else
            resp.sendRedirect(reqt.getContextPath() + "/faces/login.xhtml");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void destroy() {

}
}
```